# Confusion about a proof of the continuity of the "inverse of" function

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand a proof about the continuity of the function $inv: L_{is}(E,F)\ni T \rightarrow T^{-1} \in L_{is}(E,F)$, where $E,F$ are Banach spaces and $L_{is}(E,F)$ is the Banach algebra of all isomorphisms together with the operator norm. The proof I'm reading (from "Analysis II" by Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher) does that by assuming $2\|A-A_0\|<\|A_0^{-1}\|^{-1}$ and then showing (through the use of the Neumann series), that $inv(A)-inv(A_0)\leq2\|A_0^{-1}\|^2\|A-A_0\|$. How does this show the continuity of $inv$? I really can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_n \to A_0 $ then $$|| A_n^{-1} -A_0^{-1}||\leq 2||A_0^{-1} ||||A_n -A_0 || \to 0$$
hence $A_n^{-1} \to A_0^{-1}$.